# R + OpenStreetMap + ggplot2 + change tick marks

Tags: r, ggplot2, openstreetmap

I'm trying to manipulate the axis tick marks in a UK map

```
map = openmap(upperLeft = c(60,-11), 
              lowerRight = c(49.5,3), type="mapquest-aerial")
map2 <- openproj(map)
autoplot(map2) +
  xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude")
```

[image]
I tried adding something like this:

```
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(-10,2,2), labels=paste(c(rev(seq(0,10,2)),2),c(rep("°W",5),"°","°E"),sep=""))
```

I will get an error message:
**Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the existing scale.**

(probably because the scale is set in the map object) and although it does append the labels, the axis get shifted and a gap is created left and right of the plot:
[image]
Does anyone know how I can get rid of this grey space???

*R version 3.0.0
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got warning about the already present x axis because function `autoplot.OpenStreetMap()` (actually called by `autoplot()`) already has `scale_x_continuous()` defined. So you are making new x axis.

You can remove gray area just by adding argument `expand=c(0,0)` to your scale function. This argument is included in scale function that `autoplot()` uses.

```
 +scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(-10,2,2), labels=paste(c(rev(seq(0,10,2)),2),
                                c(rep("°W",5),"°","°E"),sep=""),expand=c(0,0))
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks you very much! Do you know if there is a way to directly manipulate `autoplot` to avoid the error message?

Comment: It's not an error but warning. You make your own function for such maps but still you will need to adjust it every time. So use your existing approach and ignore the warning.